# How to create XML file from SQL Server table with XSD validation in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: sql-server, xml, validation, xsd

I have specific question, for which there is no answer for now.. :(

I have to create a xml file for export with this structure from SQL Server table...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DATA xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="t_SR.xsd">
   <t_SR>
      <SR_COMP_ID>9002</SR_COMP_ID>
      <SalesRepresentative>
         <SR_ID>19</SR_ID>
         <SR_Name>Jan Kowalski</SR_Name>
         <SR_Type>RSM</SR_Type>
      </SalesRepresentative>
   </t_SR>
</DATA>
```

I`m trying to to this with the code below:

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim connetionString As String
        Dim connection As SqlConnection
        Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter
        Dim ds As New DataSet("DATA")
        Dim sql As String

        connetionString = "Data Source=<server hostname>;Initial Catalog=<database name>;User ID=<username>;Password=<password>

        connection = New SqlConnection(connetionString)

        sql = "select id as SR_ID,name as SR_Name,SR_Type from dbo.users where not SR_TYPE='Operator';"

        Try
                connection.Open()

                adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection)

                adapter.Fill(ds, "SalesRepresentative")

                ds.WriteXml("C:\SR.xml")

                MsgBox("Done")

            Catch ex As Exception

                MsgBox(ex.ToString)

            End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

but the code generates this (for known reasons :) ):

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="true"?>
<DATA>
   <SalesRepresentative>
      <SR_ID>3</SR_ID>
      <SR_Name>Name</SR_Name>
      <SR_Type>GM</SR_Type>
   </SalesRepresentative>
<DATA>
```

How I can add the `encoding = UTF-8` and remove `standalone=yes`? And the line with the xsd schema?

How can i put the block `SR_COMP_ID`?

Comment: Well, if you want to include `SR_COMP_ID` in your XML, you need to **select** it from the database somehow!

Comment: And i know how :P :
`    select 'value' as <column_name> ...
    It will return :
    <column_name>value<column_name>
`
But see that SR_COMPID have to be child object to <DATA>,not to <SalesRepresentative>...